# Extension of a skew field to a field

Tags: modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I want to show that every finite-dimensional simple algebra admits a symmetric
Frobenius structure.

My attempt:

I know that by Artin–Wedderburn theorem, every simple ring(algebra) is a matrix ring $M_{n\times n}(R)$ over a division ring $R$.If somehow I could manage to make this $R$ to be actually a field (i.e., commutative division ring) then I can give a symmetric Frobenius form using the trace map.

My intuition says I need to take some field extension $\mathbb{k}$ of this division ring $R$, such that I will have symmetric Frobenius form on $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{k})\to \mathbb{k}$ by using the trace map and the restriction map on $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{k}) \to \mathbb{k}$  will give me symmetric Frobenius form on $M_{n\times n}(R) \to R$. I am not sure if I make sense or not.

Any solution/hint or a reference will be of grat help!

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but how can you extend a non-commutative division $R$ to a a commutative division ring $k$? (For if $k$ contains an subring isomorphic to $R$, then it is not commutative.)

Comment: @RobArthan, can we see division ring $R$ just as a subset in the extended field $\mathbb{k}?$

Comment: I can't see how an embedding of $R$ in $k$ that didn't have any good algebraic properties would help.

Comment: @RobArthan, I think using a tensor product we can make such a field extension $\mathbb{k}$

Comment: I can only say "good luck!".